The image of a torus is a closed subtorus
I'm starting to study Toric Varieties and I was trying to prove a proposition, the hint was the statement below, but I could not find a proof for this.
Proposition. Let $\varphi:\mathbb{T}_1\rightarrow\mathbb{T}_2$ be a morphism of tori that is a group homomorphism. The image $\varphi(\mathbb{T}_1)\subseteq\mathbb{T}_2$ is a closed subtorus.
Any help will be appreciate.

I don't have a clear image of a "morphism of tori" cause I saw different sources and I couldn't understand it. In my notes a "morphism of tori" is an homomorphism of algebraic varierties.
